# Adding column to a Pandas df checking whether date range ever falls on a given month in any year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have a dataframe of entries where we want to know which entries have ever existed within a given month of any year. Simplified eg:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
         "start": [dt.datetime(2020,1,1), dt.datetime(2020,8,1), dt.datetime(2020,8,1)],
         "finish": [dt.datetime(2021,12,1), dt.datetime(2021,6,1), dt.datetime(2022,6,1)],
     })
```

How can we add a column determining which entries ever existed on any July of any year? We can add this if we're only concerned for July 2020: `df['existed_in_july_2020'] = (df['start'] < dt.datetime(2020,7,1)) & (df['finish'] >= dt.datetime(2020,8,1))`, but this doesn't have other years, and the third entry existed in July 2021.

In this eg df that column `existed_in_july` would be:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
         "start": [dt.datetime(2020,1,1), dt.datetime(2020,8,1), dt.datetime(2020,8,1)],
         "finish": [dt.datetime(2021,12,1), dt.datetime(2021,6,1), dt.datetime(2022,6,1)],
         "existed_in_july": [True, False, True]
     })
```

How can we create this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use month periods with test july month in list comprehension:

```
df['existed_in_july'] = [(pd.period_range(a, b, freq='m').month == 7).any()  
                         for a, b in zip(df['start'], df['finish'])]
print (df)
 
        start     finish  existed_in_july
0 2020-01-01 2021-12-01             True
1 2020-08-01 2021-06-01            False
2 2020-08-01 2022-06-01             True
```

Answer (score 2):

One option that should work would be to check if either July of the start or finish year is in between the two dates, or if more than one year elapsed between the two:

```
m1 = df['start'].add(pd.DateOffset(month=7)).between(df['start'], df['finish'])

m2 = df['finish'].add(pd.DateOffset(month=7)).between(df['start'], df['finish'])

m3 = df['finish'].sub(df['start']).gt('1Y')

df['existed_in_july'] = m1|m2|m3
```

Output:

```
       start     finish  existed_in_july
0 2020-01-01 2021-12-01             True
1 2020-08-01 2021-06-01            False
2 2020-08-01 2022-06-01             True
```

Comment: Any reason why you unaccepted the answer? I believe this is the most efficient as is doesn't need to create an expensive `date_range`, but I'd be happy to get some feedback ;)